# Counting values of 'a' satisfying : a XOR x > x and 0 < a < x

Tags: bit-manipulation, sequence, xor

Given a number `x`, I want to count the all values of `a` satisfying the below conditions :

> (a XOR x ) > x ;
>
> 0 < a < x ;
>
> 0 < x < 10^10

I have done it in `O(x)` as `x` can be as large as `10^10` can anybody give a algorithm to minimize the steps to count values of `a`.

[Click here for XOR operation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of looking at the most significant bit of a? If x contains a bit greater than this bit, you have a hit. So the number of bits is then just the 2^n, with n in [most sign bit of a+1, most sign. bit of x]. Haven't worked it out in detail, but I guess that's about it.

Comment: @atlaste - can you give me an example of your work

Answer (score 1):

Let's say x is 33. In binary, this gives:

x: 0000 0000 0010 0001

You're interested in the cases where `a^x > x`. It's easy to see from just the bits if this is the case:

- If a=1, it toggles the first bit to a 0, hence gives a 'false' on the condition.
- If a=3, it toggles the first and second bit, henge gives a 'true' on the condition

More general, you should look at the most significant bit you're toggling. For a=1, this is bit 1; for a=3 this is bit 2. Toggling a bit in x that is 1 won't count, while toggling a bit that's 0 will result in values that you count. In other words, both a=2 and a=3, will count, because these are all the values that toggle bit 2.

So how many values are there that hit a bit? That's simple: `2^n` where n is the bit number. So for bit 2, in our example this gives `2^1 = 2`.

The rest is just a matter of summing the intermediate results, and you're done.

Comment: can you give me total counts for x=10000

Comment: @PankajGautam I'm happy to help with algorithmic challenges, but I don't feel like doing anyone's (home)work. So that's would be a no.